# Build Manual GitlabCI pipeline job using specific Commit ID

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, devops, gitlab-ci

I need to build a Gitlab CI pipeline manually but not using latest of my master branch, but using a specific commitID.
I have tried running pipeline manually by using variable as below and passing its value but of no use.

```
Input variable key: CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

Answer (score 3):

At the time of this writing, GitLab only supports [branch/tag pipelines](http://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22886), [merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html) and [scheduled pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html). You can't run a GitLab pipeline for a specific commit, since the same commit may belong to multiple branches.

To do what you want, you need to create a branch from the commit you want to run the pipeline for. Then you can run the manual pipeline on that branch.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69763946/5752730) for step-by-step instructions on how to create a branch from a commit directly in the GitLab UI.

Comment: I am not sure about this. If the commit has the hash in multiple branches as they both originate from the same commit at some point, then I would expect that it does not make a difference for the pipeline which branch to run it from. Note that, you can create branches from commits. Given that you can do this, I think it does not make sense not to run a pipeline from a commit hash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761824/can-a-deleted-gitlab-branch-be-restored/69763946#69763946 - Also, there seems to be a feature request for this: gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22886

Comment: Yes, I think you're right in that it *can* be implemented in theory. My comment was based on the fact that (as of now) GitLab only supports [branch/tag pipelines](http://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22886), [merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html) and [scheduled pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html). That feature request is 3 years old, so I wouldn't hold my breath :) I'll update my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Use the existing (created by Gitlab CI) workspace to run the .gitlab-ci.yml and from there checkout the code again in a different directory using commitID, and perform all the operations there.