# Can a deleted GitLab branch be restored?

Tags: gitlab

There is a Git branch which was deleted by GitLab when closing a merge request.  I would like to restore (undelete) that branch; however, I'm not seeing an option in the UI to do so.

In GitHub it is possible to restore a branch deleted by a pull request after the fact (via the "Restore branch" button on the pull request).  I'm wondering if GitLab has an  analogous feature for closed merge requests.

I can of course do this manually through the Git command line, checking out the last commit hash for the deleted branch, and pushing it back up to the deleted branch name.  However, I would rather use the UI for something like this if it exists.

How can I restore a branch which GitLab deleted when closing a merge request?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Restoring a deleted branch is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18633), so GitLab has not implemented this feature at the time of this writing.

However, if you know the commit ID (and it hasn't been pruned), you can [create a new branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/web_editor.html#create-a-new-branch) from that commit:

1. From the Web UI, go to Repository > Commits
2. Find the commit you want and copy the SHA to your clipboard
3. Go to Repository > Branches
4. Click "New Branch"
5. Enter a branch name
6. Click the "Create from" drop-down menu and enter the commit SHA. Press enter to apply it.
7. Click "Create Branch"

[image]

Comment: It didn't occur to me to use the approach I suggested for the command line within GitLab itself.  Your proposed workaround is definitely technically restoring the branch from the GitLab UI, even if it wasn't the one click button approach I was hoping for.

Comment: @M.Justin This workaround is probably the reason why the new feature has been open for 4 years and counting :)

Comment: These steps helped to restore it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done from the local command line, which you'll likely need to find the SHA of the relevant commit as well. The process is described [on the GitLab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/accidentally-deleted-branch-how-to-restore/37386):

- Find the SHA1 ID of the branch's last commit by running `git reflog`
- Create a new branch with the same name, based on that commit:
  `git checkout -b <branchname> <sha1>`
- Push the new branch to GitLab

Since the new branch has the same name, existing links should be restored, e.g. open MRs will be repopulated with the vanished changes.

Comment: You can also create the branch using the SHA1 directly in GitLab.